# Required license is missing: Sitecore.Ecommerce

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

Does anyone know how to resolve this sitecore.ecommerce license error?

```
Required license is missing: Sitecore.Ecommerce
```

This is the exact same code that we have on our production server and it works fine.

Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003)

Here is my dataFolder key:

```xml
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySitecoreSite\Data" />
```

I ran the following tool to verify the license file reference: [SITECORE CONFIGBUILDER (SCB 1.4)](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_configbuilder.aspx)

And found the following key:

```xml
<setting name="LicenseFile" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySitecoreSite\Data\license.xml" />
```

**Update:**

The fix was using a different license file provided by Sitecore.

Comment: It could be that you license on your development machine missing the license for Ecommerce

Comment: @AhmedOkour All the files, including the license file, came directly from our production server.

Comment: Double check that the data folder is not being patched somewhere b doing a showconfig.aspx. Failing that it sounds link an issue with your license being used in a development environment. It's worth contacting your account manager at Sitecore to confirm that your license is valid for use in a dev environment.

Comment: @IanGraham When I try to view showconfig.aspx I get the same error for the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what licenses are available, open Sitecore Desktop, then go to **Control Panel ⇀ Administration ⇀ Show Licenses Installed on This System**.

In all likelihood, you will not find "Sitecore.Ecommerce" or "Sitecore.EcommerceFundamentals" in the list.

Find out whether the license file you *think* is being used is actually the one being used. The easiest way is to simply remove the **license.xml** file from your data folder and try to access **/sitecore**. This should then fail with the following message:

> The resource you are trying to access requires the following license: Runtime.

I feel that after following these steps you'll make sure that the right license file is used and that it does not have the Ecommerce license. This will mean that you need to get ahold of another license file.

Comment: Is it possible that the license is tied to a specific server? I get the same error when I try to login to the Sitecore admin or if I delete the license.xml file.

Comment: Ah, but if the error you get is about Ecommerce, even when you delete the license.xml, that probably means that it gets the license file elsewhere.  @AllanHorwitz

Comment: I do not think the license file was elsewhere. I think the error message was cached even after a reboot.

Comment: @ADH can you make a clean installation of the site, without a license, and then try to access it? Tell me what error you're seeing then.

Comment: I updated the originally question above with more details. The new error message is not related to this error. It is for a database connection string.

Comment: @ADH I advice that you post your findings as an answer instead of updating your question. This will help people who have this problem in the future.

Comment: Actually, I am now getting the license error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98354/discussion-between-adh-and-dmytro-shevchenko).